# Install odoo in windows

Tags: installation, odoo

I need to install ubuntu in windows without any virtualization or any third party terminal.

because I stucked in to find the best solution for the ubuntu in windows.

I don't need to install VirtualBox for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello folks,**

I always need to find a way to make odoo crystal clear in windows. so every day I wake up and try to find a better way to start all odoo version in my single window system **without virtualization**.

Finally one day I found the best solution for it, Simply go to Microsoft app store and download the ubuntu application, It will provide the ubuntu windows that will have all your ubuntu functionality without any virtual machine or anything.

Please Go for it, It'll worth it.

Thanks, windows for giving this feature.

**Links:-**

1) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804-lts/9n9tngvndl3q#activetab=pivot:overviewtab

2) Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71?activetab=pivot:overviewtab